# "At the moment" or "in the moment"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I'd always thought "at the moment" was the only correct one, but then I saw "in the moment".

There's a composer talking about his work life and he says: "I totally believe in what I'm doing *in the momen*t" (from Cambridge's Complete CAE book).

1. Do they mean the same thing?
2. Is "in the moment" mainly British?

Comment: Please add the immediate context and a link to your example. And show research: a Google search for "in the moment" quickly turns up 'How to Live in the Moment: 8 Steps (with Pictures) - wikiHow
www.wikihow.com › ... › Emotional Health › Happiness & Optimism
How to Live in the Moment. Living in the moment is all about living like there's no tomorrow.'

Comment: There's a composer talking about his work life and he says: "I totally believe in what I'm doing in the moment"
It's Cambridge's Complete CAE book

Comment: You always thought "at the moment" was the only correct way to say *what*?

Comment: I'd say that means something different from "I totally believe in what I'm doing at the moment / at this point in time". [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=In%20The%20Moment) has: In The Moment: 

You are characterized as “in the moment” if wherever you are, whatever you are doing, your mind and body are right there as well. I'm liking UD more every day. // Collins Cobuild warns against confusing the expressions: 'Be Careful!
Don't say 'I'm very busy in the moment' or 'I'm very busy in this moment'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"At the moment" means right now. For example, "He's asleep at the moment".

"In the moment" means with a special focus on the present time. For example, "living in the moment" means paying special attention to what you're doing at that particular time, as opposed to looking back on the past or planning for the future.

Comment: Thank you, this was precise.

But is it as common in American english as in British english?

Comment: "At the moment" and "in the moment," with the meanings David Schwartz explained, are common in American English as well.